# Indicate in page title if I have changes to my Recent Activity

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

I often have many tabs open in my browser while I work away, and like many others, I routinely go to my SOFU pages and hit refresh to see if there have been any answers to my questions or comments to my posts or other positive or negative feedback.

I would like to propose a feature request that would provide an addition to the page title that appears on the browser tab/title bar, which would indicate that there has been some recent activity.  This would be triggered at the same time that the Recent Activity mail icon is colored, and preferably also if there has been some modification in my rep.  The indication could look something like the '(1)' that you see on your GMail page title to indicate a new mail in your inbox.  Alternatively, it could be as simple as an asterisk.

It would also be nice if this could be polled via AJAX so that it isn't dependent on a manual or custom-scripted page refresh request.  (Note that I am not requesting an auto update to the full page,  as in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/refresh-on-the-frontpage), but simply an update to the page title).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Poll in background for StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ inbox events and update the titlebar accordingly à la Facebook](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66712/poll-in-background-for-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-inbox-events-a)

Answer (score 4):

This would be great for those of us who have our browsers minimized while we work on other stuff.

Glancing down at the title is easier than stopping what we're doing, opening up the browser, refreshing the page, minimizing, and getting back into the swing of things regarding our work.

[image]