# Show number of mod flags & pending suggested edits in window title

Tags: feature-request, moderation, flags

As a moderator, I want to take care of flags and suggested edits as soon as possible.

Many times, I have wished that the number of flags/edits would appear in the window title.  This would **increase the speed in which flags are dealt with** and also increase efficiency.

Is it possible that we could combine this related [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request):

> [Poll in background for StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ inbox events and update the titlebar accordingly à la Facebook](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66712/poll-in-background-for-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-inbox-events-a)

with this one, and *mod flags/edits would be combined* to the same number? e.g. `Super User (13)`? Or even differentiate?  Like inbox notifications would be plain number, and mod flags/edits would have an asterisk (or some other symbol)? e.g. `Super User (2, 3*)`

Of course, it would also be nice if it **auto-refreshed**, without any user interaction.

Thoughts?

Comment: Doesn't the dashboard title present the number of flags?

Comment: On Gaming, the title of my window clearly says 3 moderator flags when I look at the dashboard right now. Is that not the case on SU, or something?

Comment: ah, @GraceNote, I was confused. it shows it in the window title only when I'm on this page: http://stackexchangesite.com/admin/dashboard

Comment: That's the dashboard I was refering to. I like the number staying there. I'm not opposed to having it auto-refresh, but I think it works best when it's just there, and not on every page.

Answer (score 3):

We have had `(n)` notification of chat messages, with `(*)` accentuating pings, for a long time now.

[image: chat ping]

A while ago we got similar notifications of activity on the sites themselves (excluding SO).

[image: main site notification]

[image: click to update]

We get updates to votes, rep, the multicollider (in fact I got one as I was writing this), and probably other things (most, I believe, after this feature request was originally made). There are so many live updates now that I don't think it would be much trouble to add a flag notification too.

As for the nature of the flag notification, I'm not all that picky. I'm not so concerned about suggested edits, though including them would be great. Simply updating the flag count on the info bar would be a good start, but it would be much better to include the page title notification, especially a `(*)` or, as Gilles mentioned, a `(♦)` for mod flags to differentiate it from the normal page updates. This could be on either just the homepage, just the mod page (as [Grace Note suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84098/show-number-of-mod-flags-pending-suggested-edits-in-window-title#comment206176_84098)), or all pages (any combination, really). It could be available to 10ks or just mods. It could be disabled on SO (or the whole trilogy if they don't want that many).

Bottom line: I humbly request flags be added to the ever growing list of things for which we get live updates, preferably with an accompanying title notification.

Comment: Mod flags should add (♦) to the title.