# Notification without reload

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Poll in background for StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ inbox events and update the titlebar accordingly à la Facebook](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66712/poll-in-background-for-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-inbox-events-a)

StackOverflow needs to reload browser to check for new notifications. Of course the number of notifications are clearly shown in a balloon but this need to reload the page. I request this to be automatically updated without reloading the page. Also if the number of notification are displayed on the browser's title bar it would be easy to check for people who are working on multiple tabs with multiple works.

Comment: The browser title bar part is a good point.

Comment: Thanks and even without refreshing page too helps me. You know know to look at your comment I reloaded my page and looked at notification bar to check whether I have any new notifications. I hope using AJAX will reduce time without reloading :)