# Is there a page just for inbox updates?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox

Is there a page just for showing new inbox notifications? Right now I have to flip back to a StackExchange page to see if I have new notifications. Often I end up leaving the "Newest questions" page open, which can be somewhat distracting but at least reminds me to check for updates every so often.

My searches turned up [requests for an inbox RSS feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85897/is-there-a-rss-to-the-stack-exchange-inbox-how-about-to-activity), but that's not what I'm looking for. [This request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127139/show-inbox-updates-in-the-page-title), for inbox updates in the page title (akin to how the "newest questions" page behaves) is the closest match to what I'm looking for. However, I don't think inbox updates should be shown on every page, just on one specific Inbox page. This would provide less potential for confusion, since there would just be one number in the page title instead of two. It would also offer the advantage of being able to show inbox notifications for *every* SE site, not just the local site as in that question.

Comment: You mean something like [this page](http://stackexchange.com/users/2590771/computerfreaker?tab=inbox) (linked from the bottom of the inbox popup)?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes, except that doesn't update in realtime or show new notifications in the page title. I'm more looking for a realtime heads-up akin to what the "newest questions" page does.

Comment: The inbox dropdown already sort of does this now. Is this feature request still applicable, or should it be marked as [status-completed] (or closed as no longer reproducible)?