# Show question updates in the page title

Tags: feature-request, title, live-refresh

Since [Show inbox updates in the page title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127139/show-inbox-updates-in-the-page-title) hasn't been picked up, I propose a different use of the page title.

Whenever "something" is updated on a question, the title should reflect the number of changes or at least that changes exist.

My motivation behind it is that I'm interested in the question itself when I browse SE. I want to keep the tab open and see if there are updates to the question without opening the tab.

It should be easy to implement since the updates are already coming in.

[image]

**Proposed updates that should be counted:**

- Edit to question
- New answer
- Edit to an answer
- (if there are no answers yet, number of new comments)

Comment: Why only show comment updates if there aren't answers?

Comment: The number might be *too big* and if there are answers, they are much more important. Edits to question/answers also may be direct result of comments.

Comment: @gnat I'm really not sure why this would be a duplicate since the update sources are different. The duplicate that random found is the real duplicate, but it also was inexplicably closed as duplicate of the same question.

Comment: I see. Retracted a vote for "my" dupe