# Live-refresh of the number of pending review jobs

Tags: feature-request, review, live-refresh

With reference to the question [Refresh on the frontpage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/refresh-on-the-frontpage), when reviewing in SO, we have to refresh the page every now and then to view the newly added entries to the review queue.

However, votes and reputation are updated on the display as soon as a vote is cast, and as soon as reputation changes. Is it possible to integrate this kind of feature to see the number of pending entries in the review queues page.

This request is probably not a duplicate of [Live Updates for Review Pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132985/live-updates-for-review-pages), where the feature is requested for a counter in front of the title of the page. But, my question adresses the [dashboard for reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/).

[image: stackoverflow reviewers dashbord]

Comment: @Ben I have edited my post. It is also about refresing the numbers on the review landing page