# Does review queue page refresh automatically?

Tags: discussion, review, live-refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Live-refresh of the number of pending review jobs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152388/live-refresh-of-the-number-of-pending-review-jobs)

I thought that review page with all review queues would refresh itself automatically. But if review page is showing 0 pending reviews and I refresh my page a few times in a quick succession I would see some pending reviews. I have never noticed the queues go form 0 to other values automatically. So I wonder is this a correct way to keep manually refreshing the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not refresh automatically. So, yes, this is the "correct" way to do it because live updates are not in place.

According to [Geoff Dalgas' May 2012 edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/132985/revisions) to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132985/live-updates-for-review-pages this is [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) so look out for it changing.